# MVC3 Partial View - Can the DIV be inside the Ajax.BeginForm?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

This is what i need to do:

I have a Partial View (PV):

```
    @if (Convert.ToBoolean(ViewData["IsLogged"].ToString())) 
    {
        <div id="onlineStatus">
            ONLINE >>
            @Html.ActionLink("Take a Break", "GoOffline", "Account")
        </div>
    } 
    else 
    {
        <div id="offlineStatus">
           IN A BREAK >>
            @Html.ActionLink("Go Online", "GoOnline", "Account")
        </div>
    }
```

I put this PV on the *_layout.cshtml* so anytime i click on the **ActionLink**, the page should stay the same and the PV should only redraw itself in an asynchronous way.

I'm reading about using **Ajax.BeginForm** and it seems it needs a  but my question is:
Q1: Shall I put the  inside the **Ajax.BeginForm** ??

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions {  
           UpdateTargetId="divStatus", 
            InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace }))  {    
<div id="divStatus">  
    @if (Convert.ToBoolean(ViewData["IsLogged"].ToString()))  
    {  
        <div id="onlineStatus">  
            ONLINE >>  
            @Html.ActionLink("Take a Break", "GoOffline", "Account")  
        </div>  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        <div id="offlineStatus">  
           IN A BREAK >>  
            @Html.ActionLink("Go Online", "GoOnline", "Account")  
        </div>  
    }  
</div>  
}
```

CONTROLLER ...to return itself?

```
    public ActionResult GoOffline()
    {
        GoOffline();
        ViewData["IsLogged"] = "False";
        return PartialView("_OnlineStatusCtrl");
    }
```

PROBLEM:
The entire page redraws as the PV so I guess it is NOT drawing itself inside the

Is the problem how i call the **Ajax.Beginform** ?
Is the problem that I put the  inside the **Ajax.BeginForm** ?
Is the problem that I should put the **Ajax.BeginForm** on the **_layout.cshtml** instead?

...is it's just that I simply still don't understand MVC ??

:--)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need a Ajax form for this. You could wrap the PV in the div with the id divStatus and then use the following for the ActionLinks;

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Take a break", "GoOffline", "Account", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divStatus", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace })
```

Your controller would stay the same. This should work as expected

Comment: that solution works but creates a different problem because one of the PV contains a `<script>` and when I replace it with one that does NOT contain a `<script>` ...for some reason the `<script>` remains ...and that is causing problems.

Comment: Can I just confirm that the setup is as follows;

<div id="divStatus">
    @Html.Action("GoOffline", "Account")
</div>

Your PV does not house the divStatus tag, this remains outside of the PV. If this is the way you have it then it should not leave any script tags behind, everything in the divStatus tag should be replaced

Comment: I fixed the problem as follow:  
<div id="divStatus">  
@if (Convert.ToBoolean(ViewData["IsLogged"].ToString()))  
{  
        <div id="onlineStatus">  
            ONLINE >>  
            @Html.ActionLink("Take a Break", "GoOffline", "Account")  
        </div>  

        @Html.RenderPartial("_PingServer");
    } 

-----------------
That Html.RenderPartial ...works now when I removed the "@"